# IOS App Encryption

Tags: ios, swift, encryption

I am about to submit a new Sales app to the Apple App Store.

The users need to send their sales data to their head office daily.
To do this the app zips the sales data and attaches the zipped file to an email. This zipped file is encrypted for security, and will only be used by the head office.

Would my app be regarded by Apple as containing encryption when I submit it to the App Store ?

Comment: You *are* using encryption, so I guess so

Comment: what kind of encryption you are using

Comment: I am using SSZipArchive with password protection

Comment: Maybe I am mistaking 'encryption' for 'password protection' ?

Comment: Yes, your app is using encryption. It's not that mysterious.

Comment: I find this illogical. It is legal to password protect a zip file in an email, but if my app does this I have to jump through these hoops ?

Comment: If my answer was helpful would you consider accepting it?

Answer (score 1):

The [Apple Developer Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Documentation/License_Agreements__Apple_Developer_Program/Apple_Developer_Program_License_Agreement_20180604.pdf) states that, when distributing your app,

> You certify that (i) none of the Licensed Applications contains, uses
>   or supports any data encryption or cryptographic functions; or (ii) in
>   the event that any Licensed Application contains, uses or supports any
>   such data encryption or cryptographic functionality, You certify that
>   You have complied with the United States Export Administration
>   Regulations, and are in possession of, and will, upon request, provide
>   Apple with a PDF copy of Your Encryption Registration Number (ERN), or
>   export classification ruling (CCATS) issued by the United States
>   Commerce Department, Bureau of Industry and Security and PDF copies of
>   appropriate authorizations from other countries that mandate import
>   authorizations for that Licensed Application, as required.

So in order to comply with Apple's guidelines you must select that your app does utilize encryption on iTunes Connect if you are encrypting something inside of your app.